# tesseract-ocr reading text from image with character cordination

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I need to read text using **Tesseract OCR**  and I need to get character position from the image there is any way to achieve these task please help me

Comment: Have you tried reading tesseract documentation?

Comment: yes  I got the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, I am using Tesseract with hocr

> hOCR is an open standard of data representation for formatted text obtained from optical character recognition. The definition encodes text, style, layout information, recognition confidence metrics and other information using Extensible Markup Language in the form of Hypertext Markup Language or XHTML

Command line syntax like

```
tesseract someimage.jpg hocr
```